# AsyncRabbitTemplate vs. SyncRabbitTemplate : What are the differences in practice?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm working with RabbitMQ in Java using AMQP. I like to use annotations and I have some listeners with @RabbitListener format. my `@RabbitListener`s push to another queue once they do their processing; sample code as follows:

```
@RabbitListener(queue = "testQueue")
void subscribeToTestQueue(Message message)
{
  try {
    // ... do processing
  rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(newQueue, processedMessage);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // ... handle exception
  }
}
```

I'm looking to create a highly scalable system and obviously looking at the asynchronous `asyncRabbitTemplate`. I can't understand what benefits it would give me if I would use it, given that `@RabbitListener` is already asynchronous itself. Also, if I make the change, how should error handling change?